# how to convert xml to crystal reports, using c#

Tags: c#, xml, crystal-reports

it´s my first question here so tell me if any additional data is needed.

I´m using c# (visual studio community 2017) to read an xml file, and I´m trying to convert the xml into a crystal report format.

When I drag and drop a field from the "database fields section" to the crystal report in the header or footer sections everything is ok, but when I drag and drop some fields to the details section everything appears in blank.

The xml structure is as follows:

< cfdi:Receptor Rfc="ABC123" Name="EXAMPLE INC" CFDI="P01" / > (fields rfc, name and cfdi are ok in the report)

( these next fields are the ones I dont know how to add in the details section )

```
    < cfdi:Concepto Cantidad="2" Unidad="PZA" NoIdentificacion="365" Descripcion="POSTE" ValorUnitario="25.55" Importe="51.10" ClaveProdServ="23251800" ClaveUnidad="H87">

      < cfdi:Impuestos>

        < cfdi:Traslados>

          < cfdi:Traslado Base="51.1" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="8.18" />

        < /cfdi:Traslados>
      < /cfdi:Impuestos>
    < /cfdi:Concepto>
    < cfdi:Concepto Cantidad="2" Unidad="PZA" NoIdentificacion="225" Descripcion="BSH" ValorUnitario="19.27" Importe="38.54" ClaveProdServ="27111500" ClaveUnidad="H87">
      < cfdi:Impuestos>
        < cfdi:Traslados>
          < cfdi:Traslado Base="38.54" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="6.17" />
        < /cfdi:Traslados>
      < /cfdi:Impuestos>
    < /cfdi:Concepto >
```